# Can I create a O365 admin user without a mailbox?

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-office-365

I want to create an O365 admin account to use only for administration of exchange online so it doesn't need a mailbox- I don't want to pay for it.

Is this possible or do I have to buy another subscription for this user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible, just create the user and don't assign it any license.